# How to close Drawer upon button click(close) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a method to close drawer if clicked on a close button created on the top right corner of the drawer.

Mock of drawer:

[image: drawer mock]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just call Navigator.of(context).pop();

Example:

```
ListTile(
  title: Text('Item 1'),
  onTap: () {
    // Update the state of the app.
    // ...
    // Then close the drawer.
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
),
```

#### References

- [Drawer](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer)

Comment: That was quite simple

Answer (score 0):

To globally manage the flutter drawer what you can do is,

Add the Global key to your scaffold to manage opening and closing your drawer programmatically.

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          body:YOUR_WIDGET,
      );
}
```

To open the drawer globally,

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
```

To close the drawer globally,

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

This way you can manage the drawer open and close event globally.

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.pop is closing everything (dialogs, pop the activity, the app sometimes)

If you use a global key as suggested by @Jay Mungara, you can use this:

```dart
void closeDrawers() {
  if (scaffoldKey.currentState != null) {
    if (scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen) {
      scaffoldKey.currentState!.closeDrawer();
    } else if (scaffoldKey.currentState!.isEndDrawerOpen) {
      scaffoldKey.currentState!.closeEndDrawer();
    }
  }
}
```